# readline with for loop issue

Tags: python, python-3.x, file, loops

I have a .txt file with 10 sort lines of text (three comma separated words each), but the following only reads four of the lines in the text file:

```
def main():
    path = '/path/to/file.txt'
    f  = open(path, 'r')
    for line in f:
        s = f.readline()
        print(s)
    f.close
main()
```

but this will read all the lines but into a list:

```
def main():
    path = '/path/to/file.txt'
    f  = open(path, 'r')
    s = f.readlines()
    print(s)
    f.close
main()
```

Why doesn't the for loop work?

Comment: I think `for line in f` also reads a line, `f.readline()` reads the next line in line

Comment: ValueError: Mixing iteration and read methods would lose data
I'm stunned it works at all.

Comment: That's because the file objects are iterator-like objects. That means when you iterate over your object you're consuming its lines once, and in `readline` part your reading the next line.

Comment: Thanks for your input, for your information Rolf, it certainly didn't work well, I had no idea that the for loop already read in a line, nice to know.

Answer (score 3):

When using `for line in f` you're already reading a line. So it's useless to do `readline()` since it will read the next line which explains why you get 4 lines read instead of 10.

Comment: Thanks, yes looking at it again now, I can see my loop is now reading two lines and only printing one. Taking out the s = f.readline() solved the problem.

Answer (score 1):

This would work to get all the lines:

```
with open('/path/to/file.txt') as fp:
    for line in fp.read().split('/n'):
        print(line)
```

Answer (score 1):

When you open your file.txt, you got an `_io.TextIOWrapper` object as f.

`for line in f:` will iterate on the `f` iterator to yield each line of your file successively,line by line, into your `line` variable. You can see how iterators work [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9884132/what-exactly-are-pythons-iterator-iterable-and-iteration-protocols).

When the `f` iterator moves one line after the start of your loop, you read another line with your `s = f.readline()` and that moves your iterator one more line ahead. When you end your first loop, another line of f is read with your `for line in f:` then, you skip that line by reading the next line with `s = f.readline()`.

Your code will work with

```
def main():
    path = '/path/to/file.txt'
    with open(path, 'r') as f:
        for line in f:
            print(line)

main()
```

Answer (score 0):

`for line in f:` is already iterating over the lines in the file, you are then attempting to `read` a line within that iteration. Just use the value of `line` and forget about `s`